# error LNK2019 and LNK2001 with VS2010 and Qt Library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, lnk2019, lnk2001

I'm trying to reproduce the Qt example "webbrowser" (from qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/examples/activeqt/webbrwowser) with VS2010 ((I work on windows7 x64).

So, I copied all files (.h and .cpp) from webbrowser folder to my project.
Also, in Project properties-->Linker-->input-->additional directives I added the following libraries:

```
phonon4.lib
QAxServer.lib
Qt3Support4.lib
QtCLucene4.lib
QtCore4.lib
QtDeclarative4.lib
QtDesigner4.lib
QtDesignerComponents4.lib
QtGui4.lib
QtHelp4.lib
Qtmain.lib
QtMultimedia4.lib
QtNetwork4.lib
QtOpenGL4.lib
QtScript4.lib
QtScriptTools4.lib
QtSql4.lib
QtSvg4.lib
QtTest4.lib
QtUiTools.lib
QtWebKit4.lib
QtXml4.lib
QtXmlPatterns4.lib
```

Now, when I press Debug button, I get these errors:

```
1>------ Inizio compilazione: Progetto: web_browser, Configurazione: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: class QVariant __thiscall QAxBase::dynamicCall(char const *,class QVariant const &,class QVariant const &,class QVariant const &,class QVariant const &,class QVariant const &,class QVariant const &,class QVariant const &,class QVariant const &)" (?dynamicCall@QAxBase@@QAE?AVQVariant@@PBDABV2@1111111@Z) non risolto nella funzione "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(void)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: bool __thiscall QAxBase::setControl(class QString const &)" (?setControl@QAxBase@@QAE_NABVQString@@@Z) non risolto nella funzione "public: void __thiscall Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_MainWindow@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: __thiscall QAxWidget::QAxWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (??0QAxWidget@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) non risolto nella funzione "public: __thiscall WebAxWidget::WebAxWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (??0WebAxWidget@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QAxWidget::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QAxWidget@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual void * __thiscall QAxWidget::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QAxWidget@@UAEPAXPBD@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual int __thiscall QAxWidget::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QAxWidget@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAxWidget::connectNotify(char const *)" (?connectNotify@QAxWidget@@MAEXPBD@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QAxWidget::sizeHint(void)const " (?sizeHint@QAxWidget@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QAxWidget::minimumSizeHint(void)const " (?minimumSizeHint@QAxWidget@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAxWidget::resizeEvent(class QResizeEvent *)" (?resizeEvent@QAxWidget@@MAEXPAVQResizeEvent@@@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "protected: virtual void __thiscall QAxWidget::changeEvent(class QEvent *)" (?changeEvent@QAxWidget@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual class QAxAggregated * __thiscall QAxWidget::createAggregate(void)" (?createAggregate@QAxWidget@@UAEPAVQAxAggregated@@XZ) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QAxWidget::createHostWindow(bool)" (?createHostWindow@QAxWidget@@MAE_N_N@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual char const * __thiscall QAxWidget::className(void)const " (?className@QAxWidget@@UBEPBDXZ) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual bool __thiscall QAxBase::propertyWritable(char const *)const " (?propertyWritable@QAxBase@@UBE_NPBD@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual void __thiscall QAxBase::setPropertyWritable(char const *,bool)" (?setPropertyWritable@QAxBase@@UAEXPBD_N@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: virtual void __thiscall QAxWidget::clear(void)" (?clear@QAxWidget@@UAEXXZ) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QAxWidget::initialize(struct IUnknown * *)" (?initialize@QAxWidget@@MAE_NPAPAUIUnknown@@@Z) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "private: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QAxWidget::parentMetaObject(void)const " (?parentMetaObject@QAxWidget@@EBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ) non risolto
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QAxWidget::translateKeyEvent(int,int)const " (?translateKeyEvent@QAxWidget@@MBE_NHH@Z) non risolto nella funzione "protected: virtual bool __thiscall WebAxWidget::translateKeyEvent(int,int)const " (?translateKeyEvent@WebAxWidget@@MBE_NHH@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: virtual __thiscall QAxWidget::~QAxWidget(void)" (??1QAxWidget@@UAE@XZ) non risolto nella funzione "public: virtual __thiscall WebAxWidget::~WebAxWidget(void)" (??1WebAxWidget@@UAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\Cristina\Desktop\OpenCV\Progetti\ARUCO\web_browser\Debug\web_browser.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 21 esterni non risolti
========== Compilazione: 0 completate, 1 non riuscite, 0 aggiornate, 0 ignorate ==========
```

Here is main.cpp file:

```
#include <C:/Users/Cristina/Desktop/OpenCV/dep/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/include/QtGui/qapplication.h>
#include <C:/Users/Cristina/Desktop/OpenCV/dep/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/include/QtGui/QMessageBox>
#include <C:/Users/Cristina/Desktop/OpenCV/dep/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/include/QtGui/QProgressBar>
#include <C:/Users/Cristina/Desktop/OpenCV/dep/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/include/QtGui/QStatusBar>
#include <C:/Users/Cristina/Desktop/OpenCV/dep/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/include/QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <C:/Users/Cristina/Desktop/OpenCV/dep/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/include/QtCore/QAbstractEventDispatcher>

#if defined(Q_WS_WINCE_WM)
#include "ui_mainwindow_windowsmobile.h"
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#endif

//! [0]
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, public Ui::MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow();

public slots:
    void on_WebBrowser_TitleChange(const QString &title);
    void on_WebBrowser_ProgressChange(int a, int b);
    void on_WebBrowser_CommandStateChange(int cmd, bool on);
    void on_WebBrowser_BeforeNavigate();
    void on_WebBrowser_NavigateComplete(QString);

    void on_actionGo_triggered();
    void on_actionNewWindow_triggered();
    void on_actionAbout_triggered();
    void on_actionAboutQt_triggered();
    void on_actionFileClose_triggered();

private:
    QProgressBar *pb;
};
//! [0] //! [1]

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    setupUi(this);

    connect(addressEdit, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), actionGo, SLOT(trigger()));
    connect(actionBack, SIGNAL(triggered()), WebBrowser, SLOT(GoBack()));
    connect(actionForward, SIGNAL(triggered()), WebBrowser, SLOT(GoForward()));
    connect(actionStop, SIGNAL(triggered()), WebBrowser, SLOT(Stop()));
    connect(actionRefresh, SIGNAL(triggered()), WebBrowser, SLOT(Refresh()));
    connect(actionHome, SIGNAL(triggered()), WebBrowser, SLOT(GoHome()));
    connect(actionSearch, SIGNAL(triggered()), WebBrowser, SLOT(GoSearch()));

    pb = new QProgressBar(statusBar());
    pb->setTextVisible(false);
    pb->hide();
    statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(pb);

    WebBrowser->dynamicCall("GoHome()");
}

//! [1] //! [2]
void MainWindow::on_WebBrowser_TitleChange(const QString &title)
{
    setWindowTitle("Qt WebBrowser - " + title);
}

void MainWindow::on_WebBrowser_ProgressChange(int a, int b)
{
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) {
    pb->hide();
    return;
    }
    pb->show();
    pb->setRange(0, b);
    pb->setValue(a);
}

void MainWindow::on_WebBrowser_CommandStateChange(int cmd, bool on)
{
    switch (cmd) {
    case 1:
    actionForward->setEnabled(on);
    break;
    case 2:
    actionBack->setEnabled(on);
    break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_WebBrowser_BeforeNavigate()
{
    actionStop->setEnabled(true);
}

void MainWindow::on_WebBrowser_NavigateComplete(QString)
{
    actionStop->setEnabled(false);
}

//! [2] //! [3]
void MainWindow::on_actionGo_triggered()
{
    WebBrowser->dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", addressEdit->text());
}

void MainWindow::on_actionNewWindow_triggered()
{
    MainWindow *window = new MainWindow;
    window->show();
    if (addressEdit->text().isEmpty())
    return;
    window->addressEdit->setText(addressEdit->text());
    window->actionStop->setEnabled(true);
    window->on_actionGo_triggered();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionAbout_triggered()
{
    QMessageBox::about(this, tr("About WebBrowser"),
        tr("This Example has been created using the ActiveQt integration into Qt Designer./n"
           "It demonstrates the use of QAxWidget to embed the Internet Explorer ActiveX/n"
           "control into a Qt application."));
}

void MainWindow::on_actionAboutQt_triggered()
{
    QMessageBox::aboutQt(this, tr("About Qt"));
}

void MainWindow::on_actionFileClose_triggered()
{
    close();
}

#include "C:/Users/Cristina/Desktop/OpenCV/dep/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/examples/activeqt/webbrowser/tmp/moc/debug_shared/main.moc"

//! [3] //! [4]
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
#if defined(Q_OS_WINCE)
    w.showMaximized();
#else
    w.show();
#endif
    return a.exec();
}
//! [4]
```

Where I am wrong??
Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you have an answer to your own question, please add an answer to your own question instead of changing the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. I linked libraries for release mode, but I compiled in debug mode. So the right libraries to link are:

```
     phonond4.lib
    QAxServerd.lib
    Qt3Supportd4.lib
    QtCLucened4.lib
    QtCored4.lib
    QAxContainerd.lib
```

and so on.
Hope it is of help to someone!